# <fstream> weird memory leak in release mode

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, fstream

i am monitoring my memory consumption with a memory manager, which basically tracks all global new/delete allocations/deallocations.
I wrote a File class utilizing  behind the scenes and my memory manager always reports an error, but only in RELEASE mode (vs 2017). I investigated this and saw that when "open" is called on an fstream object, it allocates a _Fac_node in "locale0.cpp" for a static object:

```
__PURE_APPDOMAIN_GLOBAL static _Fac_node *_Fac_head = 0;

void __CLRCALL_OR_CDECL _Facet_Register(_Facet_base * _This)
{   // queue up lazy facet for destruction
   _Fac_head = new _Fac_node(_Fac_head, _This);
}
```

Can anyone explain this to me? :D
I could not figure it out when this "_Fac_head" will be destroyed in Release-Mode. In Debug-Mode a proper deconstructor is called in this file and destroys this "_Fac_head".

Thanks for any Advice :)

Comment: Where's your `delete _Fac_head;`?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely this is the internal representation of a std::facet that is going to be handed over to a std::locale, thus this should be no memory leak:

> Overload 7 is typically called with its second argument, f, obtained directly from a new-expression: the locale is responsible for calling the matching delete from its own destructor.

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/locale

Very possible that your static analysis tool cannot track that.

Comment: Hm this explains why, but does not offer me a solution. :/ I mean it tracks the allocation but because the object is static it will be deallocated when the program terminates, but how can adapt my memory manager to work with this? Do you have any idea? I thought of not using <fstream> but im not sure if e.g. the old C fread etc use this too under the hood.

Comment: Can't you just ignore it or add an exception in your tool? The standard library really is not meant to be checked, you can, no you must, trust it.

Comment: Because i check this through the global new/delete this is not as easy as it sounds. I have no information about who allocates. It's great because i have full transparency how much is currently allocated even from std::string's, std::vector's etc. I try to figure out different solution and will post it here if i have found one :) Thanks for your advice